# QtQuick - QQuickItem mouseMoveEvent not working

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a QML extension by inherit QQuickItem. I need is mouse press event and move event. So I implement mousePressEvent and mouseMoveEvent but only press event working.

Below is my minimal program which should work. But first mouse press prints the event info but press and move show nothing.

```
moveitem.h

#ifndef MOVEITEM_H
#define MOVEITEM_H

#include <QQuickItem>

class MoveItem : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MoveItem(QQuickItem *paremt = nullptr);

protected:
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

signals:

};

#endif // MOVEITEM_H
```

```
moveitem.cpp

#include "moveitem.h"

MoveItem::MoveItem(QQuickItem *parent)
    : QQuickItem(parent)
{
    setFlag(QQuickItem::ItemHasContents);
    setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
}

void MoveItem::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event;
    return QQuickItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

void MoveItem::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event;
    return QQuickItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

```
main.qml

import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

import Hello 1.0

Window {
  width: 100
  height: 100
  visible: true
  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  MoveItem {
    width: 100
    height: 100
  }
}
```

This is all. When I write this for QWidget, all works fine, but for QQuickItem, only mousePressEvent working. What's wrong?

Comment: try add `event->accept()` in mousePressEvent

Comment: @eyllanesc It works anyway but I don't know why this line need only for QQuickItem.

Comment: In QWidget you also need that code